Split bounties over several answers
Many questions have several great answers: providing different valid viewpoints, or supplementing each other. Often I find it difficult to chose the answer that I want to award the bounty to. Why not allow users to distribute a bounty over several answers?

I like this idea, but I don't think it will be implemented. This has been requested network wide and while it's not actually status-declined the accepted answer by SE staff member Shog9 basically says, no:

The goal isn't to have multiple answers each containing a piece of the
puzzle. It's to have a single, correct, comprehensive answer. Bounty
provides a means of encouraging answers to tough problems by offering
a reward: allowing you to subdivide this reward creates a situation
where you're misleading those participating (who think they're
competing for a big prize but only receive a portion of it) and
potentially discouraging users from taking the time to write a
complete answer.
In short, i think it's a terrible idea. Good, useful answers will be
rewarded, by the voters who find them good and useful. If you aren't
comfortable with the "winner takes all" bounty system, then just
don't use it - there's no requirement that you do so ever.

See also: Why Isn’t There a Way to Consolidate Answers?


Okay, thanks Josh. I disagree with that answer, because cogsci is different than Stackoverflow: there each answer can be complete and still differ from all others; here no answer short of a dissertation will ever be "comprehensive". And if someone posts an answer before you, yours can only be inclusive by stealing the effort of another's research. So for cogsci a splitable bounty makes total sense.

I personally like the idea of a split bounty @what. But there's no way SE will build that just for us and not network wide... As a reminder you can offer additional bounties to reward exemplary answers, but that doesn't help split an existing bounty. And as a reminder, I'm just the messenger here! Shog9 has a lot more say than I do...

FWIW, @what, the statement "we're different than Stack Overflow" sends up a red flag for me - it's nearly always a sign of someone wanting to use the system for something it wasn't designed to do, and rather than asking, "What tool should I use to drive nails with?" they're asking, "What can I do to prevent lacerations when hammering nails with a glass bottle?"

I was just about to ping you in chat @Shog9 and ask if this is officially [meta-tag:status-declined]. Do you get notified if anyone uses Shog9 in any answer or something? ;-)

No, what linked this from a comment on the answer you linked to. It's not declined because there may be a good reason to do it that we haven't heard yet and it just hasn't had enough attention to garner - that said, I'm skeptical: the instances where it would be useful seem awful few and far between. Also, I generally hate seeing bounties used a lot on a single question - feels like spam. You've probably seen someone ending their questions with "all replies get an upvote" - this would seem to lend itself to just that sort of nonsense.

Your logic makes sense to me @Shog9. Also, what, content on the site is licensed under the cc-wiki so any answer can refer to what other answers had as long as there's attribution given... or they could read the other answers and add the same information to their own. Basically, I do see the point of having a single, accepted answer for every given question. Even if that view might be a touch idelistic on a site like ours.

Okay, thank you both. @Shog9, a question like "How can I do ... in HTML?" is fundamentally different from one like "How does ... influence human affect and behavior." Denying this difference sends up a red flag for me ;-) Maybe SE should begin to think about the fact that not all their sites need the exact same functionality, rules etc. But I accept that my reasons for splitting bounties (on cogsci, not necessarily elsewhere) may not be the good reason you haven't heard yet :-)

I marked the MSO request as status-declined, it was just an oversight that it wasn't. I see some utility in this, but it does become self-defeating.
